# typicms install resulting in errors with chmod

Tags: laravel, composer-php, content-management-system

I'm just trying to set up a new project in laravel 9 using typicms.

I run the code:

```
composer create-project typicms/base mywebsite
```

which works fine. I swap into the new file, then run

```
php artisan typicms:install
```

This is where the issue happens. The whole install goes fine, until the very end where i get this warning:

```
chmod: invalid mode: ‘-type’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
Directory storage is now writable (755).
chmod: invalid mode: ‘-type’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
Directory bootstrap/cache is now writable (755).
------------------
Running yarn...
'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm packages installed.

> prod
> npm run production


> production
> mix --production; vite build

'mix' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Assets compiled.
```

It says assets compiled, but I'm missing major files from the install, such as the admin.css, admin.js and tonnes of others that render typicms unuseable.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Seems fairly obvious you don't have yarn installed: "'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command." And the [install document](https://github.com/TypiCMS/Base#assets) says Laravel Mix is required for asset management.

Comment: laravel mix is installed and running via npm, the docs state its either, or. As far as the docs explain you don't need yarn?

Comment: Well from the output, it’s clearly trying to run it. Opening a bug on their GH page might be a better idea than asking here